# Find and sed not returning output

Tags: bash, sed, find

I am searching for a directory and only getting the last directory back, in my instance `xyz`. Then, I wanted to use sed to make this happen by replacing all other extensions to that directory.

What I have attempted:

```
find **/macml/xyz -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*__*' -type d

#Returns the following
macml/xyz
```

Then combining this with sed:

```
find **/macml/xyz -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*__*' -type d -exec sed -E "s|^[macml\/]*||g" {} \+ &
```

returns nothing,

Expected output:

```
xyz
```

Comment: `-exec sed -E "s|^[macml\/]*||g" {} \+` operates on the files' *contents* - you seem to want to modify the files' *names* though? Regardless, there is likely a simpler, more robust way to do what you want

Comment: @steeldriver like taking advantage of the `print` command?

Comment: What OS / `find` implementation are you using? At least with GNU find, you could use  `-printf '%f\n'` to omit the leading directories

Comment: ... but I'd like to understand exactly what your end goal is here, in case there's a simpler way to achieve it

Comment: If your main goal is to get rid of leading part you can try with `xargs` and `basename`.  So cmd below:
`find **/macml/xyz -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*__*' -type d | xargs -I{} basename {}`

Comment: The question is quite unclear what kind of structure you have and what you expect to be output. Please update your question!

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected output of 'xyz' from the command you have attempted, you can use the following command:

```
find /macml/xyz -maxdepth 1 -not -path '__' -type d -exec bash -c 'echo "${0##*/}"' {} + &
```

This command will return the directory 'xyz' by removing the 'macml/' part of the path.